# Return type for *this in a builder-class method - lvalue vs rvalue refence

Tags: c++, this, return-value, builder, rvalue-reference

Suppose I have a "builder" class `B` which builds a class `C`, and looks somewhat like the following:

```
class B {
public:
  // ...
  B& set_foo(Foo a_foo) { foo_ = std::move(a_foo); return *this; }
  C build() const { /* ... */ }
};
```

This is all nice and good ... until I think about what happens when my B instance is a temporary. How should I design `B` to work also as temporary/rvalue, not just as an lvalue?

- Should I write a `set_foo() &&` variant, returning a `B&&`? That would mean replicating lots of methods, and well, [DRY](https://wiki.c2.com/?DontRepeatYourself).
- Should I just return `B&&` to begin with?
- Should I do something else?

Comment: The most canonical solution is probably to have two overloads of each, `&` and `&&`. But unless `build()` is also overloaded on `&` vs `&&`, the difference compared to your current solution should be minimal. Just missed moves in some cases.

Comment: 1. How would overloading `build()` help me? 2. Is it really canonical to duplicate all of those methods?

Comment: (1) You'd want that if `B` had heavy members that can either be copied or moved into the created `C` instance. (2) I don't know. That would prevent you from missing any implicit moves, but I'm not sure if I could be bothered writing those overloads myself.

Comment: C++23's [deducing this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r6.html) parameter would make short work of this problem, allowing you to perfectly forward the return value.  I presume you are not asking about C++23 though.

Comment: If you are not overloading `build`, why do you care whether or not the builder is an rvalue or not?

Comment: @DrewDormann: You mean, I would return `decltype(*this)` or something like that?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: What if I keep the lvalue reference, then try to use it later? Isn't that UB?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if the `B` object is temporary or not, as long as `C` does not hold a reference/pointer to it, then it is perfectly safe for `set_foo()` to return a `B&` reference to `*this`. The usage would still look like: `C c = B{}.set_foo(...).build();` The `B` object won't be destroyed until after `build()` exits

Comment: You mean, someone doing `auto&& b = B().set_foo();` worries you? Even if everything was overloaded to return `B&&`, that abuse is still just as possible (with the same exact code). You can't protect against Machiavelli.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: 1. Yes. 2. How about `auto& b = B().set_foo();` ? Or `takes_builder_lref(B().set_foo())`. It's not that farfetched.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You're mistakenly assuming the use of `B` always ends with a `build()` in the same statement... but sometimes we build partially, the continue building in a later statement or elsewhere entirely. Or maybe we want to build multiple times, so we keep a builder with everything set.

Comment: MSVC has entered the chat. And it *is* far fetched. A builder is a known pattern. To abuse it is just that: abuse, not an honest mistake. Overengineering something to avoid the unlikely is an ill-advised pursuit.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I'm not sure what you mean regarding MSVC, but I don't use MSVC. Anyway, you seem to suggest just leaving it the way it is. That's definitely a possible answer. Make it one?

Comment: Would this fix the repetition problem? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b3517sYxb

Comment: @einpoklum "*sometimes we build partially, the continue building in a later statement or elsewhere entirely. Or maybe we want to build multiple times, so we keep a builder with everything set.*" - those scenarios would require storing the `B` object in a variable, eg: `B b; b.set_foo(...); C c = b.build();` in which case `set_foo()` returning a `B&` reference would still be valid.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You're right, and your sequence of statements would be the typical use. But see the last comment I wrote StoryTeller. Now, granted, it's not the code I would write, but it's only somewhat, rather than very, contrived. StoryTeller thinks I'm over-engineering this, maybe he's right.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Well, that is somewhat of an improvement over simple duplication, but it's still a lot of signature repetition of boilerplate. Think of the case of 20 or 30 different methods.

Comment: I mentioned MSVC because it has (had? Hopefully) the nasty habit of binding rvalues to lvalue references. So, even `auto &` may not be saved by taking precautions.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Ouch. Yet another reason to continue avoiding it :-P

Comment: @einpoklum (reply to comment 24m ago)  `template<class Self> decltype(auto) set_foo(this Self&& self, Foo a_foo) { foo_ = std::move(a_foo); return std::forward<Self>(self); }`.  This would correctly preserve any valid combination of lvalue, rvalue, const, volatile in the return type.

Comment: You can also have `set_foo()`, `set_foo() &` and `set_foo &&`. Pick your return types and constness of the arguments to match the case of temporaries and non temporaries.

Comment: Don't allow assignment of temporaries without copy.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Yes, that would be great, albeit in C++23. Make it an answer so I can upvote you?

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using C++23, there's a feature called [*deducing this*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/), which would allow you to [*perfectly forward*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/what-are-the-main-purposes-of-using-stdforward-and-which-problems-it-solves) `*this`, even as a return type.

```
class B {
public:
  // ...

  template< typename Self >
  decltype(auto) set_foo(this Self&& self, Foo a_foo)
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ "this" can be specified as
//                                        a forwarding reference!
  {
      self.foo_ = std::move(a_foo);
      return std::forward<Self>(self);
  }

  C build() const { /* ... */ }
};
```

In this code, the return type will match whether `*this` is an l-value, r-value, `const` and/or `volatile`.